# Rails - Failing Routes in deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, heroku

I have an app that has the following in the routes file:

```
  namespace "admin" do 
    # ADMINISTRATIVE ROUTES ONLY 
    root :to => 'home#index' 
    resources :comments do 
      member do 
        get :approve 
        get :reject 
      end 
    end 
    resources :users do 
      member do 
        get :block 
        get :unblock 
      end 
    end 
  end
```

When browing to /admin locally, I am greeted by the appropriate page. 
On the same URL on the heroku version I get a 404.  The route shows 
correctly in 'heroku rake routes'

Logs are showing:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (wrong constant name Admin/ 
homeController): 
/disk1/home/slugs/196384_c95a9e3_4463/mnt/.bundle/gems/gems/ 
activesupport-3.0.0.beta4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb: 
103:in `const_defined?'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It transpires that this is an issue with the right_aws gem that we had in our Gemfile.

Comment: I am using Devise which relies on right_aws. Because of this, it is not possible to remove right_aws from our app. How else were you able to succumb to this issue?

Comment: Update: Seems to go away with using right_aws, master branch. i.e. in gem file: gem 'right_aws', :git => 'git://github.com/rightscale/right_aws.git'

Comment: More generally, this error can happen when a gem overwrites Rails's String#camelize method.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's finding a lowercase "homeController" class, but I don't understand why. Check your file to make sure you've named your class correctly?

Comment: This actually a flaw in the error message, it's not really looking for a lower case controller.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in the ActiveSupport beta. Are you running *exactly* the same rails version?