# Routing works on dev environment, ActionController::RoutingError when pushed to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I hope someone here can help me with this issue.  I am creating a static webpage on my dev environment, so my routing file has one line in it:

```
TeaserSite::Application.routes.draw do
  root               :to => 'pages#home'
end
```

On my dev environment, this single page shows up correctly.  When I pushed this code to heroku, I get a 404 error at that page.  Log output for heroku when I visit the root url:

```
2011-02-20T23:07:36-08:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 76.28.89.32 at Sun Feb 20 23:07:36 -0800 2011
2011-02-20T23:07:36-08:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-02-20T23:07:36-08:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-02-20T23:07:36-08:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant PagesController):
```

Rails server output on my dev environment:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-02-21 02:16:58 -0500
  Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (13.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 85ms (Views: 83.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I checked the following StackOverflow questions for some precedence with this but nothing has helped.  I don't have the right-aws gem, changing config.serve_static_assets to true did not help, and I used the "git add ." command before pushing to heroku.  Anybody know what the problem could be?  For starters, is there any way I can confirm that the PagesController file was actually pushed to Heroku (aside from that calling git push heroku returns "everything up to date")?

[Rails - Failing Routes in deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085804/rails-failing-routes-in-deployment)
[Rails production static files routing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928490/rails-production-static-files-routing-error)
[Heroku: Deploying rails application troubles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729814/heroku-deploying-rails-application-troubles)

Comment: To compare your working repo to Heroku's, does `git diff HEAD..heroku/master` work?

Comment: It returns an empty file, which means there are no differences between the two, so Heroku does have my PagesController.

Answer (score 3):

Do you actually have a controller called `PagesController`. Did you make sure it is spelled correctly as the filename and in the header.

Comment: This helped me! I was looking everywhere to figure this out, so funny it was really a simple typo: UserController != UsersController

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem - everything was working fine on my development environment, but I got that error on heroku. I made some major changes in my models by deleting and changing most of the migrations files, and I suspect, RubyMine got confused and didn't pushed everything correctly. So I did the following manually in the console:

```
git add .
git commit -m "Your comment here"
git push heroku master
heroku rake db:reset # this will force migrate on everything
heroku rake db:migrate # not necessary really, but just to make sure ...
heroku restart # the important bit
```

And the problem disappeared.

Comment: I switched to a different dev environment and the problem disappeared so I can't verify that this works, but thanks.  Hopefully if someone else comes to this problem via Google, your solution will help them.

Comment: That's ok, works fine... but with that you remove the whole content of your data base... is there another way to solve that problem?

Comment: You can dump the contents of the database and import it after db:migrate. Check Heroku's documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot, here the doc: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export